# Different results when I put identical code in a function vs writing it inline C

Tags: c, operating-system, qemu

I am developing a simple OS in C and using QEMU to test it. I am trying to write some functions to be able to be called such as a print function. When I wrote the code in the main method everything works like it should as below:

```
void kmain()
{
    char* _str = "hello"; // String to print off
    unsigned char strPtr = 0; // pointer to the first character in the string
    char* vidMemPointer = (char*) 0xb8000; //pointer to video memory
    unsigned short i = 0; // indexer for video memory.
    unsigned char l = 0;// length of string
    while (_str[++l]); // count the length of the string
    while (strPtr < l) // continue until all chars have been printed
    {
        vidMemPointer[i] = _str[strPtr]; // put char in video memory
        vidMemPointer[i + 1] = 0x0f; // color of char is white
        i += 2; // increase video memory indexer by 2 to go to next block
        ++strPtr;
    }
    return;
}
```

To start I just want to make a function to count the length of a string. I created the below function:

```
unsigned char len(char* ch)

{
    unsigned char l = 0;
    while(ch[++l]);
    return l;
}
```

the main function is then changed to:

```
void kmain()
{
    char* _str = "hello"; // String to print off
    unsigned char strPtr = 0; // pointer to the first character in the string
    char* vidMemPointer = (char*) 0xb8000; //pointer to video memory
    unsigned short i = 0; // indexer for video memory.
    unsigned char l = len(_str);// length of string
    while (strPtr < l) // continue until all chars have been printed
    {
        vidMemPointer[i] = _str[strPtr]; // put char in video memory
        vidMemPointer[i + 1] = 0x0f; // color of char is white
        i += 2; // increase video memory indexer by 2 to go to next block
        ++strPtr;
    }
    return;
}
```

to use the len function. When trying to run this code in QEMU the default QEMU text flashes from visible to nothing continuously until the process is killed and the text I was trying to print off never appears. I do not understand how this could have made any difference. I really appreciate any help. Thank you very much.

Edit: I currently have a script that compiles it to object code then links the assembly code I have written and then compiles the project together into one executable. Below is my bash script for building the project:

```
rm -f *.o kernel
nasm -f elf32 kernel.asm -o asmkernel.o
gcc -m32 -c kernel.c -o ckernel.o
ld -m elf_i386 -T link.ld -o kernel asmkernel.o ckernel.o
qemu-system-i386 -kernel kernel
```

Comment: An off-by-one corner: `while (_str[++l]);`  `while (_str[l]) l++;` would make more sense.  Same for `while(ch[++l]);`  Important with `char* _str = "";`  ( I  do not see this as OP's larger problem though)

Comment: This won't halt for strings > 255 chars.

Comment: How are you compiling this? Can you compile both to assembly and compare? Running each normally does not result in different behavior.

Comment: @stark yes I know this and currently this is not a concern of mine.

Comment: @IncreasinglyIdiotic I will update my question to discuss how it is compiled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow after hours of debugging I found that it had nothing to do with my C code at all. I had an incorrect line when declaring my stack space in assembly that messed up the code when trying to create activation records. I appreciate the help.